# Laravel creating a new user from within a controller

Tags: php, laravel

How can I invoke the create method to register a user from within a controller.

A user will already be logged in when register the new user.
When doing:

```
User::create([
...
]);
```

The password is not hashed, so the register procedure must be done with another method call. In the postRegister method used by the default register process, there is this line

```
Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));
```

So how can I invoke 
    $this->create($request->all())

From with my custom controller and what parameters does it require.

Any ideas
An thanks in advance for any feedback.

```
 /**
     * Invites a new user to the current users company.
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function employeeInvite(Request $request) {


        $this->validate($request, [
           'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

          // TODO: Check user is authorized to send invites


        $user = $this->users->getUserByEmail($request->email); // get user

        if($this->userExists($user)
            && $request->user()->email != $request->email
            && $this->userHasInvite($user->id, $request->user()->company_id) == false)
        {
            // send invite
            if($this->sendInvite($request->user()->company_id, $user->id)) {
                // if worked, create succses method to send back to the user
            }


        } else
        {
            // create user
            $userData = [
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $this->random_password(6),
            ];
            $newUser = User::create($userData);

            // send invite
            $this->sendInvite($request->user()->company_id, $userData->id);
        }


        return redirect('members/company');
    } // end function employeeInvite
```

Comment: What does your custom controller code look like?

Comment: I've added the function to question, I want to call the method from

Comment: actually, based on [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#other-authentication-methods) you could make a user, retrieve it's id, and login with it's given id. alternatively, using it's model, even without hashed password. ps. creating a user with hashed password require you to explicitly `$user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'))` or using [setAttribute mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

Comment: The [`create`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php#L57-L64) method you want to use is implemented by the`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController`. So just make sure your controller extends `AuthController`, then you can use `$this->create(...)` like you described. Or, as @Tezla very well pointed out, just use the `bcrypt` helper function to encript your generated password: `'password' => bcrypt($this->random_password(6)),`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User::create()` method doesn't hash passwords by itself, so you will have to do it yourself.

Laravel's hashing function is `bcrypt()`, so your `$userData` array should look like this:

```
$userData = [
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => bcrypt($this->random_password(6)),
];
```